# How can i share a url like Safari do in my own app

Tags: ios, safari, socialshare

I want to share a url like what Safari do in my own iOS app, How can i do this?
Use socail framework can share in some specified social plartform, but in my case ,I just want to share url like Safari.

Comment: share url like safari?? what do you mean by this? are you talking about deep links which opens app when hit from safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you think on UIActivityViewController?

[image]

```
@IBAction func shareTextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // image to share
    let link = "https://www.google.rs/"

    // set up activity view controller
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [link], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```